# protobuf-net equivalent for the StreamingContext

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I'm translating some code from the DataContractSerializer to the impressive protobuf-net serializer, and one thing that I'm really missing is the [StreamingContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.streamingcontext.aspx) passed through to my [OnDeserializing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializingattribute.aspx) methods.  I'd really like to find a way to pass a bit of context information through to some of my objects during their deserialization.

My question: is this usage pattern supported in protobuf-net?  I haven't found an equivalent so far in my investigation of its APIs, but I'm not very familiar with its design so may have overlooked something.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/detail?r=412

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature with a `StreamingContext` *is supported*, but it does not currently include the `.Context` (it currently just announces `StreamingContextStates.Persistence` with `.Context = null`), if that is what you mean.I could support that by adding an overload to the serialize/deserialize methods - presumably that would solve it?

If so, please log a feature request on the [project site](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/). Since it already supports `StreamingContext` in this scenario, it doesn't sound hard.

Comment: Sweet! I logged [this](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/issues/detail?id=189) issue.  Thanks for the help!